# upper bound on this matrix norm

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

What would be the upper bound on the 2-norm (or any norm) of the following matrix product ?
Please consider the smallest upper bound.

$\|\left(I+BA^T\right)\left(I+AA^T\right)^{-1}\|< ?$

where A and B are matrices and not necessarily square, and matrix I denotes the identity matrix. 
And we also know that $\|B\|<\|A\|$

Comment: What I could do: $\|\left(I+AA^T\right)^{-1}\|<\frac{1}{1+\sigma_{min}(AA^T)}$  and also $\|I+BA^T\|<1+\sigma_{max}(BA^T)$. Thus the upper bound is $\frac{1+\sigma_{max}(BA^T)}{1+\sigma_{min}(AA^T)}$. But this is very conservative. Is there anyway to get something smaller?

Comment: According to simulation, the upper bound should be less than 1. But my proof doesn't say so!

Answer (score 1):

You can use
$$
I+BA^T=I+AA^T+(B-A)A^T.
$$
Hence
$$
\|(I+BA^T)(I+AA^T)^{-1}\|_2\leq 1+\|B-A\|_2\|A^T(I+AA^T)^{-1}\|_2.
$$
By using the SVD of $A$, one can [from the fact that $x\mapsto x/(1+x^2)$ is for $x\geq 0$ bounded by $1/2$] get
$$
\|A^T(I+AA^T)^{-1}\|_2\leq \frac{1}{2},
$$
so

> $$
> \|(I+BA^T)(I+AA^T)^{-1}\|_2\leq 1+\frac{1}{2}\|B-A\|_2.
> $$

You can of course use the triangle inequality and the assumption $\|B\|_2<\|A\|_2$ to get
$$
\|(I+BA^T)(I+AA^T)^{-1}\|_2\leq 1+\|A\|_2.
$$
(According to my random simulations, the norm can be larger than 1.)